# not able to find property in DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I am trying tu bind an AccessDataSource to a GridView in ASP.NET. 
My AccessDataSource is composed of two tables, let's say,

```
Table Data, Table Modifications
```

My query to select the data from my AccessDataSource is the following

```
SELECT Data.*, IIF(ISNULL(Modifications.Comments), ' ', Modifications.Comments) AS Comments,
               IIF(ISNULL(Modifications.Disengagement), 0, Modifications.Disengagement) AS Disengagement
               FROM (Data LEFT OUTER JOIN Modifications ON Data.[Project Number] = Modifications.[Project Number])
```

I use the query builder from Visual Studio to verify the output from the previous query and everything is OK.

Every field that are in the table "Data" are fine and don't cause exceptions to be thrown. Exemple, this will work just fine because the "Amount" column is from the "Data" table.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Amount"
        HeaderText="<%$Resources:i18n, Column_Amount %>" 
        SortExpression="Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="1%" />
```

From this point everything is fine and I move on, so I created a Boundfield in my GridView containing the data from "Modifications.[Disengagement]", like this :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Disengagement"
    HeaderText="<%$Resources:i18n, Column_Disengagement %>" 
    SortExpression="Disengagement" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="1%" />
```

But I can't seem to access any column that are in the "Modifications" table and when I launch the WebPage, I get an error like this :

```
System.Web.HttpException: Unable to find property 'Disengagement' in the selected data source.
```

I have double checked the names of my columns and the names of my variables in my code, I will continue to do so, triple check If I must, but I think the problem comes from somewhere else.

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Comment: The best thing about .NET and visualstudi is that you can debug it. Have you tried debugging and see what is effectively in your datasource ?

Comment: I am not experienced in ASP.NET, I'm not sure how to effectively use the debugger with ASP.NET, I will try this right now but do you have any tips working with debugger in ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. I was launching another query in the code from a button click and that query was not getting good data. I have fixed the problem and will implement a "singleton" like solution to manage my query strings in my code.